# Origin not updating with transforms

Tags: objects, transforms

I moved the object below with the grab tool and the origin did not update.
[image: Origin not updating]
This occurs whenever the object is moved (with any transform tool, in any manner).  Nothing in this scene has parenting.

I believe that this issue may have been aggravated by repeated use of setting the 3D cursor position, then setting object origins to it.  As a matter of fact, they move together!

Here are some things that I tried to remedy the situation, none of which worked:

> 1. Setting the object's origin to its geometry
> 2. Clearing object origin
> 3. Applying transforms
> 4. All items under the "snap" and "set origin" menus.
> 5. Selecting different objects (the origin never moves... it might still be the origin of the object in the picture)
> 6. Selecting/deselecting all objects
> 7. Saving to a different file and opening.

As, err, *intriguing* as it is that the origin is permanently locked into the 3D cursor's place, I want to know if anybody can find a solution to this.

Comment: Note that the *[object origins](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects#Object_Centers)* (the yellow/orange dots) actually did move, the *[3D cursor](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Pivot_Point/3D_Cursor)* and *[manipulator handles](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Manipulators)* are the things which did not move.

Comment: Perhaps you have a decimate modifier on the objects containing the replacement meshes, in this case remove the modifier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because your pivot point is set to *3D Cursor*.

[image]

To have the *3D manipulator widget* move with the model and not stick to where the 3d cursor is, you can use the default *Bounding Box Center* or just press <kbd>,</kbd> (comma). If you work with both, you can also use its shortcut <kbd>.</kbd> (period) to quickly switch between them.